# Optional generic type doesn't accept nil in method call

Tags: swift

Using the typed Enum feature of Swift 2 I can define some *events* that can be broadcasted and listened by my app. Doing so I can have the compiler check things for me and also I don't have to provide strings.

```
protocol Event: RawRepresentable {}

// Somewhere in a view
enum SettingsEvent: String, Event {
    case Bar
    case Baz
}

// Somewhere else in the app
enum ViewEvents: String, Event {
    case Foo
    case Bar
}
```

Events can be broadcasted, and this is the function that performs that.
I need to use two generic types because:

- protocol 'Event' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
- V is passed to another generic collection that I control

```
func broadcastEvent<E: Event, V: AnyObject>(event: E, withValue value: V? = nil) {
    // Do something with event and value. This is not the real function body
    print(event.rawValue)
    if let v = value {
        print(v)
    }
}
```

Now, this call works:

```
broadcastEvent(SettingsEvent.Baz, withValue: "aa")
```

While these don't work

```
broadcastEvent(SettingsEvent.Baz)
broadcastEvent(SettingsEvent.Baz, withValue: nil)
```

The compiler says:

> error: cannot invoke 'broadcastEvent' with an argument list of type '(SettingsEvent, withValue: NilLiteralConvertible)'
>
> note: expected an argument list of type '(E, withValue: V?)'

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type inferring is not omniscient. When invoking a generic method, the compiler has to know the generic types you are using. Type inferring cannot see what type is `nil` supposed to be so you have to specify the types explicitly.

```
broadcastEvent(SettingsEvent.Baz, withValue: nil as NSString?)
```

Also note that `String` is a `struct` so it doesn't conform to `AnyObject`. Using a literal `"aa"` will make it a `NSString`.

I don't think you will be able to combine a generic type with a default parameter value of `nil`, only by defining a separate method

```
func broadcastEvent<E: Event>(event: E) {
    broadcastEvent(event, withValue: nil as AnyObject?)
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll provide different methods. Although I'd prefer to have a single method (also because the parameters in my case are 3: `event`, `sender` and `value` and only the first is required), to the caller having an overloaded method is okay too: if you pass `value` you know that it can't be optional, and the caller doesn't have to provide a _casted_ `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by defining `AnyObject` as generic you are using the `AnyObject` protocol (not the object). The protocol does not conform to the `NilLiteralConvertible` one and so it does not recognize the *nil* literal.

In your case you should define your method like that:

```
func broadcastEvent<E: Event>(event: E, withValue value: AnyObject? = nil)
```